# How to stop my mobile menu moving my website down?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my websites menu on mobile devices. When the mobile menu is clicked the image below it moves down with the menu. Is there anyway I can use z-indexs to push the image backwards and to bring the mobile menu forward?

HTML:

```
    <header>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="">Royal Navy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">The Equpiment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Search</a></li>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" id="mySearch" value=""> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
            </button>
        </div>
        <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </li>
     </ul>

     <div class="logo"><a href="">
         <img border="0" alt="Royal Navy" src="/Volumes/NATHANSUSB/Programming/HTML/Royal Navy Website 2/Images/Logo.png" width="100px" height="119px">
     </div>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="img1">
        <img alt="Made in the Royal Navy" src="/Volumes/NATHANSUSB/Programming/HTML/Royal Navy Website 2/Images/Made in the royal navy.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.body{
    background-color:#b5b5b5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}
.logo{
    margin: -50px 0 -20px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    }

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #4169e1;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

.search{
    margin: 14px 0px -20px 420px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:100;
  }

  .logo{
      display:none;
  }

  .search{
    display:none;
  }

  .img1{
    z-index:-1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just `z-index` won't do anything - you need to float the part of the menu that comes down

Comment: Please post relevant HTML and CSS... Some of your CSS is cut off.  Better, replicate the problem in JSFIDDLE or CODEPEN so we can clearly see the problem and offer a solution.  One hint though is to make your header position:absolute; or position:fixed;

Comment: I need the myfunction() code to help, it obviously returns undefined, provide the js.

Comment: Thanks will have ago. Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Nathan_1998/8krhfLvg/4/

Comment: What should the pic do when the menu is open?Be hidden?fly out off screen?Visible as background?

Comment: Sorry for not being very descriptive in problem. I want the image to go behind the menu when it is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already said in the comments, the content gets pushed down because it's on the same *level* as the elements toggled by clicking on the navbar.
A solution could be making the navbar have either position **fixed** or **absolute** and giving the body a padding-top value equal to the height of the navbar so that the actual content doesn't end up hidden by it.